# C IDE compiler tutorial (nothing works)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to set up an IDE for C programming.

I have tried netbeans, VS, Dev, codeblocks, eclipse and more!

Nothing seems to work, in every case as soon as I try to run/compile I get an error pertaining to the compiler/debugger not being found.

I have downloaded multiple compilers one of which I literally transferred from another computer and still -nothing- works.

I have done much more complicated things involving JAR imports with Jbox in Java and yet for this the solution eludes me.

Does anyone know of a step-by-step tutorial for setting this up?

I'm running windows8 64bit.

Comment: For setting what up?  Which IDE do you actually want to use?

Comment: At this point I don't even care, as long as it works and can compile/debug/run C programs.

Comment: well MS Visual Studio is click, wait a lot & play... and every thing is pre-installed (including things you dont want)

Comment: @stackoverflow909: well as Tomer says, Visual Studio is trivial to set up.  Install it and then ask us a specific question about it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I installed visual studio express. But when I try to create a new file, for example, I only have the options of: textfile, html page, style sheet, xml file etc. I tried creating a project also but nowhere did it say C or C++ sourcecode.

Comment: You downloaded the wrong version of Visual Studio.  http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the links will be helpful. I found Codeblocks is very simple and light weight compiler for C/C++.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/CodeBlocks_HowTo.html

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-and-Configure-Simple-Directmedia-Layer-%28SDL%29